# Install Eclipse on Windows through Chef.

Tags: eclipse, chef-infra

I am new to chef and I am trying to install Eclipse into windows 2008 using chef. I didn't find any information online on how to do that. If anyone knows how to do that, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Could you post your eclipse cookbook for windows as an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any community cookbooks that do this on Windows so you'll have to write your own cookbook. Writing a cookbook is a bit out of scope for SO. If you are unfamiliar with Chef, I suggest you start with [learnchef.com](https://learnchef.com) or the Learning Chef book.

Comment: It was actually pretty easy to install eclipse.

Comment: How did you install Eclipse on Windows through Chef? I want to do the same. Could you please explain?

Comment: Could you post your eclipse cookbook for windows as an answer please?